# HashMap doesn't write and read everything I want

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, hashmap

I'm trying to write in my database with Hashmap the receiver, the message and the sender when a user want to send a message, but the problem is that only the message and the sender is written in the database.I think the problem is that the app won't access the primary key for the receiver.

I tried to change the order in the btn_send onClick but nothing. I was thinking to add another string at the intent.getStringExtra. Maybe something like that.

The MessageActivity.java:

```
        intent=getIntent ();
        final String userid=intent.getStringExtra("FIRST NAME ");

        fuser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance ().getCurrentUser();
        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance ().getReference("users");
        reference.addValueEventListener ( new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange (@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                for(DataSnapshot snapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren ()){
                    User user=snapshot.getValue (User.class);

                    assert user != null;
                    assert fuser != null;
                    if(!fuser.getUid ().equals(user.getFirstName())){
                        username.setText (user.getFirstName());
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled (@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {}
        });
        btn_send.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick (View view) {
                String msg=text_send.getText().toString();
                if(!msg.equals("")){
                    sendMessage(fuser.getUid(), userid, msg);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MessageActivity.this,"You can't send empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                text_send.setText("");
            }
        } );
        }
private void sendMessage(String sender, String receiver, String message)
{
    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance ().getReference ();
    HashMap<String,Object> hashMap=new HashMap<>();
    hashMap.put("sender", sender);
    hashMap.put("receiver", receiver);
    hashMap.put("message", message);
    reference.child("Chats").push().setValue(hashMap);
}
```

The debugger shows me:

```
/ViewRootImpl@d19ed8[MessageActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@d19ed8[MessageActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 1
D/InputMethodManager: prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@ab6a231[MessageActivity]
    getNavigationBarColor() -855310
V/InputMethodManager: Starting input: tba=com.example.sportsbuddy ic=com.android.internal.widget.EditableInputConnection@5a5e0d0 mNaviBarColor -855310 mIsGetNaviBarColorSuccess true , NavVisible : true , NavTrans : false
D/InputMethodManager: startInputInner - Id : 0
I/InputMethodManager: startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=105
    Input channel destroyed: fd=108
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
```

I expect to put in the database the receiver with his primary key.

Comment: From the log we can't see any problem, have you tried to call "Log.d(TAG, "Receiver: " + receiver);" in your 'sendMessage' method to check if "receiver" is a valid String?

Comment: I didn't try this. I'll try and come with updates

Comment: Is your intent extra key really `final String userid=intent.getStringExtra("FIRST NAME ");` (note the extra space after NAME).  As others indicate, logging receiver would help but going back to where `userid` is set that seems to be a possible source of error, since that is the actual `receiver` parameter.